# How can I make my question on-topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope

[Connecting to Oracle using ODP.NET](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/36687/c-with-oracle-odp-net-commandtext-alternatives)

I was told in the comments that it is off-topic, and someone has also downvoted it without any explanation.

I have shown code that works fine and want it reviewed. Please give your feedback.

Comment: Thank you for addressing your concern here.  I have temporarily locked your question so that further discussion can be directed here.  Once a consensus is reached, please flag for unlocking.

Comment: @Jamal I have edited my queustion. Take a look at it please. Ant it can be unlocked

Comment: It looks better now.  The lock was only for an hour, hence why you were still able to edit (locks prevent all activity from non-moderators except for flagging and favoriting).  Again, thank you for posting here.  I'll clean up the comment section now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Entity Framework** has a provider for Oracle.

That would be an alternative, and it would answer your question.

Would it be a good CR answer? Certainly not. The way I read your question, it's like asking *"How can I write this query in a strongly-typed manner, without those magic strings?"*, which is essentially *asking for code to be written*.

A Code Review answer would be more like this:

> You're using `using` blocks to dispose your disposables, which is excellent. However these blocks increase the nesting of your code; since there's nothing between `using (var oracleConnection = new OracleConnection(ConnectionString))` and `using (var oracleCommand = oracleConnection.CreateCommand())` you could drop the curly braces and write it like this:
>
> ```
>    using (var oracleConnection = new OracleConnection(ConnectionString))
>    using (var oracleCommand = oracleConnection.CreateCommand())
>    {
>        ...
>    }
> ```
>
> Within that scope, you're reassigning variable `Id` at each row that gets read; ultimately the value of `Id` will be that of the last row that was read. I doubt this is the intended behavior.

Comment: I have edited my question. Thanks for repsonse. Upvote + accept.

Comment: @MikroDel removed downvote on your original post :)

Comment: @MikroDel actually, upvoted and answered!

Answer (score 3):

The three current votes on your question are not suggesting it's off-topic, they are all 'It's unclear what you are asking'.

Your title and the actual question you have are a little bit contradictory too:

Title:

> C# with Oracle ODP.NET. CommandText alternatives

Actual question you ask:

> Is there any alternatives to write oracleCommand.CommandText as a text?

If the title of your question was: `Are there any alternatives .... ?` then this would certainly be off-topic for CodeReview. As it stands at the moment, it is just unclear.

The title suggests you are using some form of alternatives, but your code contradicts that.

Comment: I have edited my question. Thanks for repsonse. Upvote.